# Foursquare API return only specific category

Tags: ios, api, location, foursquare

I'm working with the foursquare api. I can successfully get back results nearby based on a few parameters including "query" in which I pass my search string.

I'm trying to work out if there is a way to return places of a specific category. e.g. gym, park etc. I've tried passing in a string into the "section" parameter but this had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `categoryId` parameter.

e.g. Search gym(4bf58dd8d48988d175941735):

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&categoryId= 4bf58dd8d48988d175941735&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)&v=20160324

See also:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search